#  Get injectionMemebers from Unity registrations

Tags: c#, unity-container, code-injection, member

Is it possible to get the injectionMembers for a registration in Unity container?

I want to get the registration that use a specific "`InjectionConstructor(typeof(MyClass)`".

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The `InjectionMembers` place or modify policies in Unity's `IPolicyList`. That's all that is left after the registration.